# how to parse copy link of twitter

Tags: swift, twitter

I am using this code -:

```
private static func getJson(_ link: String, completion: @escaping (Json?) -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://twitter.com/BCCI/status/1476041561288822788?s=20")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return completion(nil)
        }
        if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? Json {
            completion(json)
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I want to get json data and download the link

Comment: You are using an API that is not opened to everyone: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/overview You need to do Auth beforehand. In a nutshell, they allow only "authorized users" to query it, avoiding too much unwanted call per bots and others.

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the Twitter docs [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/overview) you'll see that it requires authentication hence the error when making the call.

```
Auth: Twitter Oauth 1.0, app-only or app-user
```

This [Twitter getting started](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/getting-access-to-the-twitter-api) link may be useful to get setup to do so, it's fairly self explanatory and goes step by step.